# How can i calculate the sum of table column in angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ngfor

I have a table that is being filtered dynamically (Pipes) according to user selection.

I need to enter a summaries row at the bottom that will show the SUM of the `item.total` column.
This is the code, what is the best way to implement it?

```
  <tbody>
      <tr class="newLine" *ngFor="let item of records | filter:profile | location:selectedRegion ">
        <td scope="row">{{item.name}} </td>
        <td scope="row">{{item.profile}} </td>
        <td scope="row">{{item.location}} </td>
        <td scope="row">{{item.numOfTags}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>{{total numOfTags??}}</tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new filter pipe that calculates the sum with the current filter

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filtercount'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    }).reduce((a, b) => a.total + b.total, 0);
   }
}
```

and use it like this

```
{{records | filtercount:profile}}
```

Comment: thanks, but what do i do if i have other pipes as well? can i separate it completely and make it run as last pipe?

Comment: can you make it clear and name your other filters? where do you want to use these filters? what do these filters do?

Comment: i have 2 other pipes "| filter:profile | location:selectedRegion" that filter rows by strings, after they made the filter i need the sum of filtered total column. (UPDATED CODE TO BE MORE CLEAR)

Comment: oh, I see you want to filter your data with locations and text searching and more. you can chain your filters and the last filter will be your new filtercount. just remove search filter from filtercount pipe and just calculate the total of the input array and with help of previous filters input array of filtercount pipe will be the filtered data and all you need to do is calculate the count of that

Comment: Great! that worked! just created new filter and put it last in the filter chain :)

Answer (score 2):

I have found another way to reproduce your code with better performance Here's the code:

```
<div    *ngFor="let item of records | yourfilterChain;let last=last;let sum=ngForOf.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)" >
     {{item}}
     <div *ngIf="last">{{sum}} </div>
</div>
```

you can calculate the sum of filtered result with arrow function inside ngfor

Answer (score 2):

It's a very simple task but most of the UI developers stuck at this point . So let's discuss.

If we have already get the response(in JSON format)from any Web Service , i.e., array of object-

```
0: {REFUND: 0, PAYMENTCANCELLED: 0, PENDING_RECHARGE: 11, OUTLIER: 0, CHANNEL: "JIO.COM", …}
1: {REFUND: 0, PAYMENTCANCELLED: 65, PENDING_RECHARGE: 0, OUTLIER: 0, CHANNEL: "JIO.COM", …}
2: {REFUND: 0, PAYMENTCANCELLED: 31, PENDING_RECHARGE: 393, OUTLIER: 0, CHANNEL: "MYJIO", …}
3: {REFUND: 0, PAYMENTCANCELLED: 319, PENDING_RECHARGE: 1, OUTLIER: 0, CHANNEL: "MYJIO", …}
```

let's consider the above response is loaded in like

```
this.FttxRechargeReportRes = response.responsePayload;
```

The above thing is common and understandable to everyone. Now , to get the sum of every values of respective keys.

```
  getSum(){
    debugger;
    console.log(this.FttxRechargeReportRes );
    let sumArr = this.FttxRechargeReportRes .reduce((acc, cur) => {
      for (let key in cur) {
        // console.log(key, cur, acc);
        if (key !== 'RTYPE' && key !== 'CHANNEL') {  // "We did this because there was only characters in RTYPE & CHANNEL , so we could not get sum of same."
          if (acc[key]) {
            acc[key] += cur[key]
          } else {
            acc[key] = cur[key]
          }
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})

    console.log(sumArr);
this.arrData=sumArr;
console.log(this.arrData);


  }
```

When you will print **arrData**, you will get the following output:-

```
{
REFUND: 0
PAYMENTCANCELLED: 415
PENDING_RECHARGE: 405
OUTLIER: 0
RECHARGE_SUCCESS: 15212
PAYMENTSUCCESS: 15617
PAYMENT_INITIATED: 23333
TOTAL_RECHARGE: 39365
}
```

You only need to print in html, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but I thought it would be useful to share my `fieldSum` Pipe.

When you have a list of object and you want to publish the sum of one of the fields.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Pipe to return the sum of `attr` fields in `items`
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'fieldSum'
})
export class FieldSumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], attr: string): number {
    // console.log('items:', items, 'attr:', attr);
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
}
```

Use like:

```
{{ items | fieldSum:'qty' }}
```

Using as a reference this pipe implementing count, average and such is trivial.